# Better way to convert structured text to business entities

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to find a better solution to convert a plain text (but with predefined lengths for each field) to a business entity. 
For example the input text can be "Testuser new york 10018", the first 11 characters indicates user name, next 12 character indicates city and next 5 characters indicates zip code.
The input text can be long like 1000 characters, which represents multiple properties in an entity

Any help appreciated..Thanks

I tried following approach

1. Defined xml structure which can be deserialized to business entity
2. use xslt to navigate to each node and fill xml element values by using substring functions on the input text.
3. Once xml is populated,deserialize the xml to entity.

But I think the above approach may not be scale able with load with multiple xslts to convert different inputs to corresponding xmls

Comment: In your example, the first 8 characters are username, the next 8 characters are city, and the next 5 characters are the zip code... (and no, it's not just space normalization.) Is that the actual format?

Comment: Define 'better'. Better than what? What have you tried? What about what you tried did not work?

Comment: @Chris, I updated the question with my current approach

Comment: Are you controlling both the output from the business entity to the string and vice-versa? Also, are you wanting the string data to be used outside of your single application (cross application)?

Comment: @Wizetux - I get string from a different application then I need to process it to business entities. I also have to convert business entity to structured text and send it to original application.

Answer (score 2):

A nice and elegant way might be to use regular expressions, in the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace, so something like this:

```
static Regex inputParser = new Regex("(.{11})(.{12})(.{5})", RegexOptions.Compiled");

foreach(Match m in inputParser.Matches(yourInput)) {
    BusinessEntity e = new BusinessEntity();
    e.Username = m.Groups(1).Value.TrimEnd(); // Remove spaces from the end; I take it that's what they'll be padded with
    e.City = m.Groups(2).Value.TrimEnd();
    e.ZipCode = m.Groups(3).Value;
    myListOfBusinessEntities.Add(e);
}
```

Comment: @ChrisShain Well, yes. If there are fields of different types, it should be easy enough to modify.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing a single situation, you can simply write a simple class with a method wich receives a text line and returns a new entity.

If you pad your lines with blanks, having a fixed length line, a binary reader with `System.Text.Encoding` class and `GetString` method  can produce a faster solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the refinement of the question, I am inferring that you have multiple different formats for different inputs. Here is an implementation of IFormatter that should get you most of the way there.  Note that this is broken in several different ways, hacky, and comes with no sort of guarantee:

```
void Test()
{
    var serializer = new FixedWidthSerializer<MyClass>();
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.Serialize(ms, new MyClass { Age = 30, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe"});
    ms.Position = 0;
    var newMyClass = (MyClass)serializer.Deserialize(ms);
}

[Serializable]
private class MyClass
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName;
    public Int32 Age { get; set; }
}

public class FixedWidthSerializer<T> : IFormatter
{
    private readonly FixedWidthFieldDefinition[] _fieldDefinition;

    public FixedWidthSerializer()
        : 
        this(FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(typeof(T)).Select(sm=>new FixedWidthFieldDefinition(sm.Name, 100)).ToArray())
    { }

    public FixedWidthSerializer(FixedWidthFieldDefinition[] fieldDefinition)
    {
        if (fieldDefinition == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("fieldDefinition");
        _fieldDefinition = fieldDefinition;
        Context = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All);            
    }

    public class FixedWidthFieldDefinition
    {
        public String FieldName { get; protected set; }
        public Int32 CharLength { get; protected set; }

        public FixedWidthFieldDefinition(String fieldName, Int32 charLength)
        {
            FieldName = fieldName;
            CharLength = charLength;
        }
    }

    public object Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
    {
        var streamReader = new StreamReader(serializationStream);
        var textLine = streamReader.ReadLine();

        if (textLine == null)
            throw new SerializationException("Ran out of text!");

        var obj = FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof (T));
        var memberDictionary = FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(obj.GetType(), Context).ToDictionary(mi => mi.Name);

        var offset = 0;
        foreach (var fieldDef in _fieldDefinition)
        {
            if (offset + fieldDef.CharLength > textLine.Length)
                throw new SerializationException("Line was too short!");

            // Read the current field and increase the offset
            var fieldStringValue = textLine.Substring(offset, fieldDef.CharLength);
            offset += fieldDef.CharLength;

            MemberInfo memberInfo;

            if (!memberDictionary.TryGetValue(fieldDef.FieldName, out memberInfo))
                throw new SerializationException("You asked for the member '" + fieldDef.FieldName + "', but it doesn't exist on type '" + typeof (T) + "'");

            var memberAsField = memberInfo as FieldInfo;

            if (memberAsField != null)
                memberAsField.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(fieldStringValue.TrimEnd(), memberAsField.FieldType));
            else
                throw new SerializationException("I don't know what to make of the property '" + fieldDef.FieldName + "'");
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public void Serialize(Stream serializationStream, object graph)
    {
        var serializableMembers = FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(graph.GetType());
        var membersToSerialize = _fieldDefinition.Select(fd => serializableMembers.First(sm => sm.Name == fd.FieldName)).ToArray();
        var objectData = FormatterServices.GetObjectData(graph, membersToSerialize);
        var sb = new StringBuilder(_fieldDefinition.Sum(fd => fd.CharLength));
        for (var i = 0; i < _fieldDefinition.Length; i++)
            sb.Append(((String) Convert.ChangeType(objectData[i], typeof (String))).PadRight(_fieldDefinition[i].CharLength), 0, _fieldDefinition[i].CharLength);
        var sw = new StreamWriter(serializationStream);
        sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        sw.Flush();
    }

    public ISurrogateSelector SurrogateSelector { get; set; }

    public SerializationBinder Binder { get; set; }

    public StreamingContext Context { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try the above approach and see how it goes